# Dark background on images in default UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background

I have a UITableView in my project with rows being initialised as default UITableViewCell (the owner file is the delegate and the datasource for the table):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_facebook.png"];
            cell.textLabel.text = kShareFacebook;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_twitter.png"];
            cell.textLabel.text = kShareTwitter;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_clipboard.png"];
            cell.textLabel.text = kShareClipboard;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

This all works fine, however when the table is displayed, the images are shown on a darker background and there is a darker margin along the right edge of the rows, as can be seen in this image:
[image: screenshot]
I've tried to clear that background using a combination of some/all:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[cell.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];
[cell setOpaque:YES];
```

however this didn't help a bit.  How can I get rid of the dark background so that the entire cell appears on white background?

Comment: did you use IB to set up the UITableView ?

Comment: I have just set up a test project and implemented the cellForRow exactly the way you have, and the cells are correctly white all over. Are you setting the cell's background to gray at any point at all ? I believe they have white background by default which is strange. Did you implement any other delegate methods such as 'tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:' which might be changing the appearance of the cell ?

Comment: I am not changing the background of the cells and I didn't implement `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have been one of iOS or, most likely, XCode's fluckes.  I deleted the table in IB and delete the corresponding code in my `.m` file.  I then saved and closed the project and quit XCode.

After opening XCode and the project, I open the ViewController in IB again and added the table again and set up all the delegates again.  I added the code to set the overall table's background to transparent (this can't be done via IB, so I put that code in `viewDidLoad` method). I then rewrote the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (no copy-paste, just re-typed it - no problem, only about 10 lines anyway) and build the project.

Lo and behold: the table was now displaying correctly.  I hate spending days on some stupid bugs in the development tools.